Where is the water coming from?
We had our shower fixed and it’s been a nightmare. Now after the job is finished water is leaking through the tile curb (see image). Is there any way it’s causing damage or is it a simple grout fix?

Water is coming out from between tiles????!!!!   That is ridiculous, YES it is causing damage.

How soon, after you start showering, do you see water seeping out of this grout line? How much? How long does it continue after you turn the water off?  Is there plumbing inside that wall ie a valve, spout, jet?  How high from the floor is that ledge? A wider shot of the whole shower might help.

@RMDman: what if there's waterproofing (e.g. Redgard) behind there?  Still causing damage?

@Huesmann, " IF"  there is waterproofing and if it was applied correctly there could be no notable damage, however if the tile and grout was done so bad it leaks under the tiles, there is not much confidence that what's under is done well.

Water coming out of any wall is cause for concern, for it is almost certainly soaking whatever is behind it every time the shower is used.  Without air to dry it, the continuous wetting will wreak havoc.  Grout and plaster will disintegrate, paint and wallpaper peel, wood studs rot, steel screws rust, grounding connections to metal electrical boxes corrode, mortar and cement effloresce, mildew and mold multiply, and termites and carpenter ants rejoice.
How to locate a leak:
If the leak only occurs when the shower is in use, it means there is a leak at a joint in the plumbing somewhere between (and including) the diverter valve and the shower head.  Unless you have access from the backside, you will need to remove shower tiles to repair it.  The leak is most likely near the top where the water comes out from between the tiles, and where you will find one or more joints joining the vertical shower feed to the shower head.
Even if I found and repaired a leak at the top, I would inspect the joint at the diverter valve and the valve itself to be sure they are not leaking also.  There are several reasons to do this:

whoever made the joint at the top may have likewise erred at the bottom
while repairing the top, you may inadvertently weaken a joint below
you may not be so lucky as to have a visible indication of a leak below
you won't want to do tile work a second time.

Notes on looking for leaks behind walls:

You may be able to look for leaks using an endoscopic camera accessory with your cell phone (~$25); it only needs a half-inch hole, which you may be able to manage behind an escutcheon plate.
Using the camera, it may be hard to say for sure whether there is dampness.  You may want to run the shower while running the camera, if you can manage that.  Any leak will be more pronounced with the water turned on and the shower head turned off (or at least maximally restricted), because it maximizes the pressure.
Note that a leak under pressure may manifest as a needle-like stream that may be hard to see with the camera.  If you spot water dripping from something other than a pipe joint, look to see if the source is such a stream.

In any event, you will want to dry the interior before recovering it.  If you haven't removed enough tiling to allow things to dry out on their own, or even if you have, you can speed the process by blowing air on it.  A hairdryer works well for this; you may use moderate heat (but avoid it on PVC), or cold air.  The hose and wand from a vacuum cleaner will also work (blowing, rather than sucking, works best to penetrate the recesses).  Even a simple fan pointed toward it is better than nothing.
